# How to "shift" query result one row further

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Let's say I have something like this:

```
$sql = $con->query("SELECT * FROM Content ORDER BY Time DESC LIMIT 2");
while ($row = $sql->fetch()) {
    echo $row['title'];
}
```

So this grabs the 2 latest entries in a table and then echoes the designated column. How can I take the 2nd and 3rd most recent entries from my table ignoring the first one?

Right now I'm thinking about setting the limit to 3 and somehow skipping the first result and grabbing the 2 remaining.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this :

`LIMIT 1,2`

1 => offset : From where to start(First one will be 0)
2 => number of records

```
$sql = $con->query("SELECT * FROM Content ORDER BY Time DESC LIMIT 1,2");
while ($row = $sql->fetch()) {
    echo $row['title'];
}
```

Comment: Awesome! This worked brilliantly. Didn't know `LIMIT` had an offset.